# sculpting tools do not add material

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

Via Google Translate:

My problem is that the tools in the "sculpture" section don't add material to my object, they just move it, as if it were a sheet. I think there is a problem with that object because I don't usually have this problem, but I can't figure out what's wrong. I have tried to change almost all the settings of the object but nothing seems to work.

As you can see from the image if I try to add some material to the upper part of the donut it only creates a "swelling" if instead I try to add it to the lower part I have no problem

[image: .]

Comment: Hello, you need to write in English in BlenderStackExchange, but have you tried to enable the Dyntopo option?

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: Ciao e Benvenuto. L'inglese è la lingua obbligatoria per il sito. Se non ti senti a tuo agio a scrivere in inglese sentiti libero di usare qualsiasi servizio di traduzione online.